# creating columns with limits and even results in each column

Tags: php

I am trying to make 4 even columns, but my code is making 3 some times. Let me explain the issue.
The number of listings per column is calculated by the $max variable.
e.g. if we have 5 results, and we have 4 columns, the $max variable will be 2 (5/4 = 1.25, ceiling = 2)
This means with the current code we would have a max of 2 listings per column, but this is not what we want. We want 4 columns, with the listings evenly spread. 
So currently it ends up as:

```
one        three        five
two        four
```

We want it to be:

```
one        three        four        five
two
```

if we had 7 results then we would want it to be

```
one        three        five        seven
two        four         six
```

if it was 10 then we would want

```
one        four        seven        nine
two        five        eight        ten
three      six
```

I hope that is enough examples for you. I just couldn’t work the logic.

Here is the code:

```
function makes($condition) {
    $makes = '<div id="'.$condition.'" class="footer_tabs_results">';
    $qry = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT `make_name`,`make_url` FROM `".$condition."_makes`");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $max = ceil($num_rows/4); // 4 is for 4 columns, works out the max checkboxes per column
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)) {    
        if($i==0 || $i%$max==0) $makes .= '<ul>'; // working out whether to start a new column
        $makes .= '<li><a href="'.URL.$row['make_url'].'">'.$row['make_name'].'</a></li>';
        $i++;
        if($i==$num_rows || $i%$max==0) $makes .= '</ul>'; // working out whether to end a new column
    }        
    $makes .= '<div class="clr"></div></div>';
    return $makes;
}
```

So what logic should I used to achieve this?

Comment: what are you getting in html? Add that html code too

Comment: Why `nine` is not under `eight`, in the case of 10?

Comment: I'm sorry but the problem is still a bit vague to me. 

You're saying that you want 4 columns, not 2. This means you're trying to force 4 columns and yet you create a variable based on the amount of rows you get back from the database. If this is the case, just set $max to 4 and you will ALWAYS generate 4 columns.

Please try to improve your question.

Comment: No the "2" is arbitrary it is created by dividing the number of rows by 4 (4 being the number of columns). 2 is for the number of rows in each column. The counting is vertical not horizontal.

Comment: Ah, now I get the logic behind it.
What's the desired HTML result you're trying to get?
Do you just float all the <ul>'s?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I was floating the uls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want to place the output *by column* (i.e. not row-by-row), so simply using one `ceil($num_rows/4)` is not enough: you'll have to calculate the `$max` every time you start a new column

```
/* ... */
$left=mysqli_num_rows($qry);
$colLeft=4;
$limit=0;
$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
    if($i==0)
    {
        $limit=ceil($left/$colLeft);
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    echo '<li>'.$row.'</li>';
    $i++;
    $left--;
    if($i>=$limit)
    {
        echo '</ul>';
        $i=0;
        $colLeft--;
    }
}
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/cc3Wj) (using array to emulate database result).

For `[1,2,3,4,5]`, the above code will output (prettified):

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li><li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

For `[1..10]`, the above code will output (also prettified):

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>7</li><li>8</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>9</li><li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But where does the 4 columns factor in? Is it from the 5 (4+1)?

Comment: @user2909486 Yes, I used 5 because the first loop will eat out one (`$colLeft--`).

Comment: @user2909486 I changed the logic a little bit to make it more reader-friendly, and also corrected the variable name from `$rowLeft` to `$colLeft`.